# AVPlayer won't let me access URL

Tags: swift, xcode, avplayer

I am Attempting very simple Xcode OS X program with swift 4.0 - this program builds and runs but I'm getting errors accessing the URL video file. Probably related to privilege or security setting somewhere but can't figure out where. Here is my program under class ViewController: NSViewController:

```
@IBOutlet var playerView: AVPlayerView!
//var url: URL!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    // guard let url = URL(string: "https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/samplecode/avfoundationMedia/AVF oundationQueuePlayer_HLS2/master.m3u8")
    //    else {
    //        return
    //    }

   let url1 = URL(string: "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4")


    let player = AVPlayer(url: url1!)
    // Create a new AVPlayer and associate it with the player view

    let playerView = self.playerView
    playerView?.player = player
    playerView?.player!.play();
}
```

Also I have modified the info.plist file with the following:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict/>
</dict>
```

*I get the following runtime errors trying to access either of the URLs
 above why?*

> 2017-11-05 10:12:21.757333-0800 AVPlayer[54381:5617593] startLogging:
>   logging starts... 2017-11-05 10:12:21.758024-0800
>   AVPlayer[54381:5617612] setMessageLoggingBlock: called 2017-11-05
>   10:12:21.758520-0800 AVPlayer[54381:5617612] initWithSessionInfo: XPC
>   connection interrupted 2017-11-05 10:12:21.758842-0800
>   AVPlayer[54381:5617612] startConfigurationWithCompletionHandler:
>   Failed to get remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.rtcreportingd"
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named
>   com.apple.rtcreportingd} 2017-11-05 10:12:21.759003-0800
>   AVPlayer[54381:5617612] startConfigurationWithCompletionHandler:
>   Failed to get remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain
>   Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.rtcreportingd"
>   UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named
>   com.apple.rtcreportingd} 2017-11-05 10:12:21.925221-0800
>   AVPlayer[54381:5617654] App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext
>   HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary
>   exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found your question after you commented on a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937036/playing-hls-m3u8-in-cocoa-os-x-avplayer-swift/37938025?noredirect=1#comment81429115_37938025) I had answered previously, so lets continue here :)

I can get your code working by combining my original answer to that question with the answer provided by @callam above so...give him the credit for the correct answer :)

To summarize, you need to:

1. Add a `AVPlayerView` to your Storyboard and connect it to your `ViewController`
2. Setup your `ViewController`
3. Manage App Transport Security and the outgoing connection.

In greater detail

### 1. Add a `AVPlayerView` to your Storyboard and connect it to your `ViewController`

Drag a `AVKit Player View` to your view in the storyboard

[image: Add AVKit player view]

In your `ViewController` class, create an `outlet` for the view:

```
 @IBOutlet weak var playerView: AVPlayerView!
```

And connect it.

### 2. Setup your `ViewController`

Here is my code:

```
import Cocoa
import AVKit

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var playerView: AVPlayerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let fileURL = URL(string: "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4")
        let avAsset = AVURLAsset(url: fileURL!, options: nil)

        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: avAsset)
        let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
        playerView.player = videoPlayer
        videoPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

Seems familiar no :)

Notice I create the `videoPlayer` right here, no need to for me to use the `let playerView = self.playerView` you mention in your comments.

If you just do these two steps, you end up with a player view that cannot play video and errors in your console. So you need to add the final piece to the puzzle, kindly provided by @callam above.

### 3. Manage App Transport Security and the outgoing connection.

First, if you cannot use a `HTTPS` connection you must allow `HTTP` connections in your `info.plist` file.

Here is my `.plist` file in its entirety

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSMinimumSystemVersion</key>
    <string>$(MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET)</string>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string>Copyright © 2017 :) </string>
    <key>NSMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>NSPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NSApplication</string>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The important part being the `NSAppTransportSecurity` part

And then finally, you must enable `Outgoing Connections (Client)` under `Capabilities` of your project

[image: enable Outgoing Connections]

If I do that, I end up with this:

[image: The final result]

But notice though, that I still see errors in the console.

Hope you are able to get to the same result following these steps :)

Comment: Got it working thanks so much for all your screen shots! What happened was in my "Referencing Outlets" section I did not have a playerView --------> View Controller connection. I had to redo the CNTRL drag of my Player View to the class to get a connection. So thanks much it was the exact screen shot I needed!

Comment: @NealDavis its the little things eh :) Glad you got it working in the end.

Comment: This worked for me! My issue was not having `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` in Info.plist. Cheers @pbodsk !

Answer (score 4):

Even if you enable arbitrary loads, attempts to connect using insecure HTTP fail.

Change the protocol in your URL to `https://` or add the domain to `NSExceptionDomains`.

```
let url1 = URL(string: "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4")
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW35

I believe the XPC error can be fixed by selecting `Outgoing Connections` in your App Capabilities

[image: App Sandbox]

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html

Comment: change to:  let url1 = URL(string: https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4) still getting same errors: 2017-11-05 15:28:14.574696-0800 AVPlayer[54923:5681894] initWithSessionInfo: XPC connection interrupted
2017-11-05 15:28:14.575333-0800 AVPlayer[54923:5681894] startConfigurationWithCompletionHandler: Failed to get remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.rtcreportingd" (basically same as above?)

Comment: Yes did add https://   - not sure what the comment doesn't show it but you can click on the link and see that it works

Comment: notice the failure appears to be: Failed to get remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.rtcreportingd" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.rtcreportingd}  - com.apple.rtcreportingd seems like it would say something about https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com ???

Comment: added <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia</key>
        <true/>  still same errors as reported above

Comment: @NealDavis I have added a screenshot

Comment: added both incoming and outgoing per your screenshot still get same errors: 2017-11-05 21:12:42.236064-0800 AVPlayer[55535:5754173] initWithSessionInfo: XPC connection interrupted
2017-11-05 21:12:42.236524-0800 AVPlayer[55535:5754173] startConfigurationWithCompletionHandler: Failed to get remote object proxy: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "connection to service named com.apple.rtcreportingd" UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=connection to service named com.apple.rtcreportingd}

Comment: - I still get the errors above but I hear the sound track of the video - so it is playing I just don't see the video? Any ideas why I hear the sound but don't see the video?